# Increase all product prices by some percentage Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, updates, product

I have around **4000 products** in **woocommerce**  and there prices has been set,

Now I want to **increase** the prices of **all** products by some **percentage**.

Like I have a product price say 100  and I want to add 40% in it to  make 140 .

I need to do this for all 4000 products

Please suggest to me how can I achieve this.

Comment: Are all your products simple products?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before proceeding **please take a backup** of the database and run the following query using PHPMyAdmin or some other similar means.

To update regular price

`update wp_postmeta set meta_value = meta_value * 1.40 where meta_key='_regular_price'`

To update sale price, run the same query just change the meta_key to _sale_price